# проверить родителя у блока

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="parent">
  <div>
   <span class="child"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как проверить, что child находится в родительском блоке с классом parent?

Answer (score 1):

В примере выше child НЕ находится в родителе с классом parent. Я привёл пример, в котором это утверждение будет истинным. Если это именно то, что нужно.

UPD:

Написал небольшую рекурсивную функцию. Можно вглубь искать родителя с нужным классом.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.child').parentNode.classList.contains('parent'));
console.log(document.querySelector('.child2').parentNode.classList.contains('parent'));

function hasClassedParent(el, cssClass) {
  if(el.parentNode && el.parentNode.tagName !== 'BODY') {
    if(el.parentNode.classList.contains(cssClass)) {
      return el.parentNode;
    } else {
      return hasClassedParent(el.parentNode, cssClass);
    }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

console.log(hasClassedParent(document.querySelector('.child3'), 'parent')); // returns element
console.log(hasClassedParent(document.querySelector('.child4'), 'parent')); // returns null
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
   <span class="child"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <span class="child2"></span>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div id="f">
    <div id="s">
      <span class="child3"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="p">
  <div id="f">
    <div id="s">
      <span class="child4"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: В примере c child возвращает false, а должен true

Comment: Обновил ответ. Простым способом не получится. Написал небольшую функцию.

Answer (score 1):

С jQuery

```
$(".child").parent().hasClass("parent") ? alert("Yes") : alert("No")
```

Comment: не работает такой вариант. Возвращает false

Comment: @WoodRest Конечно будет возвращать false, span с классом .child находится в div без класса, его родитель не div.parent. Если нужно получить true, то попробуйте $(".child").parent().parent().hasClass("parent") ? alert("Yes") : alert("No")

Comment: Так тоже false выдает

Comment: @WoodRest https://codepen.io/NarekEVN/pen/wvaOwXM
Вот пример, проверяйте.

Answer (score 1):

### На чистом JS, без библиотек и рекурсивных функций.

Метод [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) возвращает ближайший родительский элемент (или сам элемент), который соответствует заданному CSS-селектору или null, если таковых элементов вообще нет.

```js
document.querySelector('.child').closest('.parent')
  ? alert('true')
  : alert('false');
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
   <span class="child"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я свой ответ удалил, когда вчитался в вопрос. Решение было аналогичным, но исходя из вопроса, неверным. Может я не так понял вопрос или ТС не так сформулировал. Но, для `span.child` родителем является `<div>` без класса, а уже у этого блока родитель `div.parent`.

Comment: @UModeL не удаляйте ответ, если ТС не может сформулировать нормально и понятно для всех свой вопрос, то это проблема именно ТС'а. В моем понимании нужно найти родителя с необходимым `CSS`-селектором. Даже приведенный `html` код как бы намекает на поиск родителя через пустой `div`

Comment: ну, теперь поздно восстанавливать, раз у Вас то же решение.

Comment: @UModeL можете восстановить свой ответ и я удалю свой, решение явно лучшее в данном вопросе и не соревнуется с другими, оставьте повторно ответ, я не гонюсь за статистикой, мне главное помочь кому-то

Comment: не-не, всё норм. Я тоже здесь не из-за репы ;-) Когда пытаешься объяснить, то сам лучше начинаешь понимать сабж.

Answer (score 0):

Если имеется в виду родитель родителя:

```
let parentOfParent = document.querySelector('.child').parentNode.parentNode;

let isTheParent = parentOfParent?parentOfParent.classList.contains('parent'):false;
```

Если подниматься по ветке и искать родителя с классом `parent`,то надо рекурсивно подняться по дереву DOM